# Mock non static method of a class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to write a test with stubbing but mocking one of the methods does not happen as expected.

```
class A {
 public static getInstance(){
  return new A();
 }
 public String getConn(){
 return "Hello";
 }
}

class B {
 public String createConn(){
  A instance  = A.getInstance();
  return instance.getConn();
 }
}
```

My Test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  
@PrepareForTest(A.class) 
public class TestClassB{  

  @Spy 
  B classB = new B();  

  @Test 
  public void testConn(){  

      PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);  
      given(A.getConn()).thenReturn("Welcome");  
      assertEquals("Welcome", classB.createConn()); 
  }
```

I want to create a test on Class B, `createConn` method, and when I get the connection, instead of "Hello", I want to receive "Welcome" using mockito?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried?

Comment: `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class TestClassB{
 @Spy B classB = new B();

@Test
public void testConn(){}
 PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class); 
given(A.getConn()).thenReturn("Welcome"); 
assertEquals("Welcome", classB.createConn());
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of the problem.

```
  PowerMockito.mockStatic(A.class);
  PropertyManager mock = PowerMockito.mock(A.class);
  given(A.getInstance()).willReturn(mock);
  given(mock.getConn()).willReturn("Welcome");
  assertEquals("Welcome", classB.createConn());
```